# Swift variable accessibility

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I am doing this for a class, so I am not looking for someone to code this for me, just for a little guidance. Using Swift3 in Xcode 8. I fixed the previous errors and I *think* I'm making progress but...

```
class Cat {

        var catName, catBreed, catColor: String
        var catAge, catWeight: Int

        init(name:String, age:Int, weight:Int, breed:String, color:String)

        {
            catName = name
            catAge = age
            catWeight = weight
            catBreed = breed
            catColor = color
        }

    func calculateAge (catAge: Int) -> Int
    {
        var humanYears = 0

        if catAge == 1 {
            humanYears = 15
        } else if catAge == 2 {
            humanYears = 24
        } else if catAge > 2 {
            humanYears = (24 + (catAge * 4))
        }
        print ("Your cat is \(humanYears) human years old!")
        return humanYears
    }
    func createCats(name: String, age: Int, weight: Int, breed: String, color: String) -> String
    {
        let humanYears = calculateAge(catAge: age)
        let catInfo : String = "\(name) is a \(color) \(breed) who weights \(weight) named \(name), and he is \(humanYears) human years old."
        print (catInfo)
        return catInfo
    }
    }
Cat.createCats()
```

I get an error at Cat.createCats() stating use of instance member 'createCats' on type 'Cat'; did you mean to use a value of type 'Cat' instead?

I have tried putting Cat in the (), I have tried naming all of my variables in there...

Comment: When do you expect this print statement to run? You cannot just have floating code in a type – you need to put it in a function.

Comment: Just put `print` above `return humanYears`. Then very time `calculateAge` get called message will be print.

Comment: Hi Hamish, I expect it to run at the end of the function. I tried placing it above the return as beeth0ven suggested. Since I am running this in a playground, I expected to see something on the sidebar. I get no errors, but no results either.

Comment: @JeffR Are you calling the `calculateAge` method? You'll need to call it in order to see the result in the playground sidebar (and the console). As a side note, I see no reason for `calculateAge` to be an instance method as it doesn't utilise any instance state – I would make it `static`/`class` instead (or make it an instance method, but use the `catAge` property as input).

Comment: @Hamish, Wow, talk about a noob mistake. No sir I forgot to call the method. There are more instructions to the task I am working on, where I have to create several instances of the Cat and change the values, this is why I chose to make it an instance method. Is this still correct?

Comment: @Harish, and the hits just keep on coming. Another noob mistake of mine that you found, thank you for your insight, I have remove the extra declaration of humaYears.

Answer (score 0):

As I see  in your code , you are re-declaring the variable "humanYears". 
One is immediate after Class and second is in the function "calculateAge" . Edit your function "calculate" as below :

```
func calculateAge (catAge: Int) -> Int {

        if catAge == 1 {
            humanYears = 15
        } else if catAge == 2 {
            humanYears = 24
        } else if catAge > 2 {
            humanYears = (24 + (catAge * 4))
        }
        return humanYears
}
```

Comment: I've made some changes. In addition to calculating the human years, I need to be able to instantiate a Cat with the default values, but also instantiate a Cat with alternate values, and each time print the Cat details.

Comment: not getting your point , please add the updated code for more understanding

Comment: I updated the original post, is that not the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, thanks to you guys and another post on Stack Overflow that I searched up. Just in case it helps anyone here, I will post my final code below. My biggest issue was that I was trying to call the function before I created an instance of the class. This is not the finished version of the solution, but I was excited that I got it working so I wanted to post it.

Thanks again for all of your help,

```
class Cat
{

    func calculateAge (catAge: Int) -> String
{
    var humanYears = 0

    if catAge == 1 {
        humanYears = 15
    } else if catAge == 2 {
        humanYears = 24
    } else if catAge > 2 {
        humanYears = (24 + (catAge * 4))
    }
    return "Your cat is \(humanYears) human years old!"
}

func createCats(name: String = "Fluffy", age: Int = 1, weight: Int = 3, breed:         String = "tabby", color: String = "brown") -> String
{
    var catInfo : String
    let humanYears = calculateAge(catAge: age)
    catInfo = "\(name) is a \(color) \(breed) who weights \(weight) pounds     named \(name), and he is \(humanYears) human years old."
    print (catInfo)
    return catInfo
}
}

let firstCat = Cat()
firstCat.createCats()
let secondCat = Cat()
secondCat.createCats(name: "bob")
```